# Number of Windows 8 Pro licenses per computer

Tags: windows-8, license, windows-8-upgrade

I have three computers that I would like to upgrade to Windows 8, and I'm wondering if purchasing the Pro version once is enough for all of them.

Here is what I saw on [the Microsoft site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/terms-conditions). I want to make sure that I understand it before buying.

> The promotional price is limited to one upgrade per PC and a maximum limit of five upgrade licenses per customer.

From what I understand, I get five upgrade licenses, so I can upgrade up to five computers and cannot reuse any one of those licenses twice. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: This is a legitimate question, but it's really about law (or, perhaps, language), not your computer. You could replace "Windows 8" and "installation" with any number of other products and actions and have essentially the same question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to purchase an upgrade for each PC that is eligible for an upgrade. You cannot use 1 upgrade on 3 PCs.

Example: If you have 3 PCs that are eligible for upgrade, and you have purchased an upgrade for each of them then you can upgrade them. If you have say 6 PCs eligible for upgrade, you can only purchase 5 upgrades at the special price, because the discounted upgrades are limited to 5 per customer. You will have to pay the regular price for each license over 5.

Comment: its a pleasure.

Answer (score 5):

You have to purchase separate license for each PC you upgrade:

> The promotional price is limited to **one upgrade per PC**…

And you can upgrade a maximum of five PCs by promotional price:

> …and a maximum limit of **five upgrade licenses per customer**.

If you need more upgrade licenses, you would have to buy them at the regular price.

Comment: Thank you, sorry i can only accept one answer and Riaan was first