# How do I upgrade windows 8 on multiple computers with my 5 license?

Tags: windows-8, installation, windows-8-upgrade

I have a problem. I bought windows 8 when they had the time where you could get 5 licenses for 40 bucks. I bought it and installed it on my computer. And I downloaded the disk to do it on another computer. The only problem is, the disk is 64 bit, and the second computer I'm trying to use it on, is 32 bit. My question is, how do I get the 32 bit version to upgrade this other computer. I do have 5 licenses to use with windows 8. Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm this isn't your case? http://superuser.com/questions/501361/number-of-windows-8-pro-licenses-per-computer

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed. I was understanding that I buy one upgrade of windows 8, and then it gives me 5 licenses to use on 5 computers. Thanks! :D